# store all value in variable with comma separate

Tags: javascript, ajax, foreach

i am try to get lat and long value from the url using ajax.
with this:-

```
$(function() { 
            var region = "Rajkot,Jamnagar,Surat";
            var cn ="IN";
            var array = region.split(',');
            for(var item in array)
            {
            var lat;
            $.ajax({

                url: "http://services.gisgraphy.com//geocoding/geocode?address="+array[item]+"&country="+cn+"&format=json",
                              async: false,
                              dataType:'jsonp',
                              success: function(data){        
                    lat = data.result[0].lat;
                    lng = data.result[0].lng;
                    alert(lat);
        }
        });                 
        }
```

here i got the latitude and longitude value.
but i want to all lat value in one variable with comma seprate.
and all lng value in another variable with comma seprate.
how its possible.
help. thanks....

Answer (score 1):

```
var lat = new Array(), lng = new Array();

var totalLength = array.length;
var count = 0;

for(var item in array) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://services.gisgraphy.com//geocoding/geocodeaddress="+array[item]+"&country="+cn+"&format=json",
        async: false,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            count++;
            lat.push(data.result[0].lat);
            lng.push(data.result[0].lng);

            if (count == totalLength) {
                var commaSeperatedLat = lat.toString();
                var commaSeperatedLong = lng.toString();
            }
        }, 
        error: function(data) {
            count++;//handle
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: when i alert(commaSeperatedLat) display blank.

Comment: See my edit. Since you are using AJAX request, you need to wait them to complete.

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K7bUr/ . Look at console. You will see that the url that you are sending the request gives internal server error.

Comment: check also this http://jsfiddle.net/K7bUr/3/ this is your code i want to get there variable value in to another function.

Comment: you need to use javascript callback in this situation. I've updated fiddle. check it out. by using callbacks, you dont have to use count. you can easily see how to do that. here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/K7bUr/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
var lat = new Array(), lng = new Array();
var latStr='',lonStr='';

 success: function(data){        
        lat.push(data.result[0].lat);
        lng.push(data.result[0].lng);
    }

  latStr = lat.join(',');
  lonStr = lng.join(',');
```